# Evaluation process of And, Or,

Tags: performance-tuning, evaluation, boolean-computation, logic

Small questions about evaluation process of `And`, `Or`.

code 1)

```
If[4<= f[5] <=9, Print["Good"], Print["Bad"]]
```

guess 1 for code 1)

1. Evaluate `f[5]`
2. Check `4<=f[5]`. Suppose that it was indeed true.
3. CPU still remember the value of `f[5]`. Check `f[5]<=9` without evaluating `f[5]` again.

code 2)

```
If[f[5]<4 || f[5]>9, Print["Bad"], Print["Good"]]
```

guess 2 for code 2)

1. Evaluate `f[5]`
2. Check `f[5]<4`. Suppose that it was indeed false.
3. CPU does not remember the value of `f[5]`.
   So evaluate `f[5]` again. Then, Check `f[5]>9`.

I would appreciate it if you tell me about the codes and guesses.

Comment: Why not `Trace`?

Comment: The reason in part 3. is not so much about remembering `f[5]`, but that there is no guarantee that `f[5]` evaluates to the same value every time. For instance, `RandomReal[5]`.

Comment: I found my answer with help of `Trace`. And I couldn't think of Random case. Thank you.

Comment: Look in the help at: Notation/tutorial/PrecedenceOfOperatorsInNotations

Comment: The `FullForm[4 <= x <= 9]` is `LessEqual[4, x, 9]`, which means `f[5]` should only evaluate once.

Answer (score 5):

I checked it with `Trace` and `Timing` (with the factorial of 10000000) and my conclusion is

For term `a<f[x]<b`, CPU evaluates `f[x]` only once.

For term `a<f[x]&&f[x]<b`, CPU evaluates `f[x]` twice if `a<f[x]` is True.

For term `f[x]<a||f[x]>b`, CPU evaluates `f[x]` twice if `f[x]<a` is False.

In fact, if `term1` and `term2` are terms containing `f[x]`, then,
for `term1&&term2`, if `term1` is `True`, CPU evaluates `f[x]` again to check `term2`. Similar logic applies to `term1||term2`

So, my recommendation is

1. use the term `a<f[x]<b` if possible. It is faster and always good.
2. do not use `f[x]<a||f[x]>b`, instead use `Module[{m=f[x]},m<a||m>b}`. it can save time to its half, in case `f[x]<a` was indeed `False`.

Comment: I would argue that this has nothing to do with computing boolean logic. An expression like `f[5]` will be evaluated everytime it's encountered during the evaluation process. I wouldn't be surprised if some built-in functions do some optimizations for special forms, but in general, I would never expect the evaluator to remember/cache values for expressions. When building your own `f`, you can implement memoization, but even that doesn't prevent evaluation of `f[5]`--it just causes subsequent evaluations to use a different (presumably more efficient) rule.

Comment: When you're building up an expression and you notice you have, for example, `f[5]` repeated within the expression, you can do your own optimization with `With`. I suppose using `Module` works too, but that form will set up unnecessary variables, whereas `With` will just slap the values into your expression in situ. This is uesful not only for optimization, but to avoid having to change multiple identical subexpressions when you're refactoring or experimenting.

Comment: @lericr This is indeed a little related to boolean logic, because evaluation may stop halfway in `&&` and `||`. As shown by OP, for expression like `expr1&&expr2`, the evaluation ends immediately once `expr1` is found to be `False`, and `expr2` will never be touched in this case.